# Nginx 301 rewrites using regex

Tags: nginx, redirect

I moved to a new software and now need to catch the old urls and rewrite them to the new ones.

Here is an example:

Old url: http://www.religiousforums.com/forum/neopagan-revival-religions-dir/19088-druid-horoscope-whats-your-sign.html
New url: https://www.religiousforums.com/threads/druid-horoscope-whats-your-sign.19088/

I tried this but it does not work:

```
    location ~* ^/forum/[^/]+/[0-9]+-[^\.]+\.html$ {
            rewrite [^/]+/([0-9]+)-[^\.]+\.html$ /threads/$1/ last;
    }
```

What am I missing here? I only need the id in the new url. The text is not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update : not clear what you want to do**

If you mean you want to serve from both URLs the same content, then you are doing **content duplication** and it's a very bad idea. Now to **redirect** correctly from old URLs to the new ones, you must set this up :

```
location ~* ^/forum/[^/]+/([0-9]+)-([^.]+)\.html$ {
    return /threads/$2.$1 permanent;
}
```

Or simply put this in a common location block :

```
location /forum {
    rewrite ^/forum/[^/]+/([0-9]+)-([^.]+)\.html$ /threads/$2.$1 permanent;
}
```

Edit: This worked:

```
location /forum/ {
    rewrite ^/forum/[^/]+/([0-9]+)-([^.]+)\.html$ /threads/$1/ permanent;
}
```

Comment: This still does not work unfortunately. Your rule is live on the url above.

Comment: @BamaStangGuy see updated answer.

Comment: Second location works perfect with location /forum/ {
    rewrite ^/forum/[^/]+/([0-9]+)-([^.]+)\.html$ /threads/$1/ permanent;
}